# How to use a preexisting unix library in java

Tags: java, linux, unix

I was using the following code without any problem for my app.

```
inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bootmenu/recovery/sbin/tune2fs -l /data.img").getInputStream();
```

However recently the tune2fs executable was replaced by tune2fs library. I cant no longer get this code to work.

I tried :

```
inputstream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bootmenu/recovery/sbin/tune2fs -l data.img",new String[]{"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/bootmenu/recovery/sbin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"}).getInputStream();
```

But without sucess, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/system/bootmenu/recovery/sbin/tune2fs", "-l", "data.img");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/system/bootmenu/recovery/sbin:" + env.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"));
pb.directory(new File("/mnt/sdcard/multiboot/MIUI/"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: I don't think $LD_LIBRARY_PATH will be resolved. You need to fetch LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the current environment and append it.

Comment: This works because "The initial value is a copy of the environment of the current process (see System.getenv())." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I get `The method directory(File) in the type ProcessBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String)` at `pb.directory("/mnt/sdcard/multiboot/MIUI/");`.

Comment: Updated the answer, you seem to be working on JDK 6+. The other syntax was for prior versions.

Comment: Two guesses: (1) The OS user that can access the command is not the same as the user running JVM. (2) Instead of using `workingDirectory` use full path: `/mnt/sdcard/multiboot/MIUI/data.img`

Comment: I cross checked and excluded 1 and 2, any other suggestions?

Comment: I ran a sample test but not on _Android OS_ as it seems to be your host OS, my guess is that either `/system/bootmenu/recovery/sbin/tune2fs` or `/mnt/sdcard/multiboot/MIUI/data.img` should be a wrong location.